# Haskell Lens: Apply a transformation to a traversal

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens

I'm hitting a wall with the following problem when using the Haskell Lens library.

Let me use the example from the ["Program imperatively using Haskell lenses"](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html) blog post by Gabriel Gonzalez.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data Game = Game
    { _score :: Int
    , _units :: [Unit]
    , _boss  :: Unit
    } deriving (Show)

data Unit = Unit
    { _health   :: Int
    , _position :: Point
    } deriving (Show)

data Point = Point
    { _x :: Double
    , _y :: Double
    } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Game
makeLenses ''Unit
makeLenses ''Point
```

It's a good toy structure. For concreteness, here's an instantiation:

```
gameState :: Game
gameState = Game
    { _score = 0
    , _units =
        [ Unit
            { _health = 10
            , _position = Point { _x = 3.5, _y = 7.0 }
            }
        , Unit
            { _health = 15
            , _position = Point { _x = 1.0, _y = 1.0 }
            }
        , Unit
            { _health = 8
            , _position = Point { _x = 0.0, _y = 2.1 }
            }
        ]
    , _boss = Unit
        { _health = 100
        , _position = Point { _x = 0.0, _y = 0.0 }
        }
    }
```

Querying units works like this:

```
gameState ^.. units . traverse . health    -- health of all units is [10,15,8]
```

Changing the health of *all* units can be done like this

```
gameState & units . traverse . health .~ 100
```

Here's where I get stuck: Suppose I wanted to apply a transformation to the traversal of the units, i.e. get the health of all the units, change all of them according to some rule, and set them. For example, if I wanted to reverse the health-list (not a very meaningful transformation in this example), something like this should work:

```
gameState & units . traverse . health %~ reverse
```

But I can't quite figure out which operator(s) to use.

I used this example as guidance (sort and replace all elements < 4)

```
[2,4,3,5,4,6,1] & partsOf (traverse. filtered (<4)) %~ sort  -- is [1,4,2,5,4,6,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular transformation, I think you're looking for:

```
gameState & partsOf (units.traverse.health) %~ reverse
```

The optic:

```
units.traverse.health
```

represents a traversal of the `_health` of each `Unit` (in the order the `Unit`s appears in the `_units` field) within your `Game`.  This is different than the lens (not traversal!) that focuses on the list of healths as an `[Int]` within the `Game` -- to get this, you need to apply `partsOf` to the traversal.

You can use the traversal directly if -- as documented in the `Control.Lens.Traversal` module -- you want to traverse over the structure changing out its contents with monadic or applicative side effects (applied in order from left to right).  However, if you want to operate on the entire list as a unit and use general `[Health] -> [Health]` transformations, you'll want to convert the traversal to the `partsOf` lens first.

Comment: Do be careful with partsOf. It does strange things (see documentation) if the list isn’t the same size (which means the lens it produces isn’t really a lens).